# Custom query: multiple custom post types

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am having some trouble pulling multiple custom post types from a [Custom Wordpress Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries). The reason I am creating a custom Wordpress query rather than using `query_posts` or `WP_query` is because I am sorting my posts based on information added by a voting plugin, and have to join that plugin's table, so the built-in queries are not an option.

My question is how can I include multiple custom post types in the same query? At present, my query looks like the following:

```
$query = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID         = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wposts.post_status  = 'publish'
    AND wposts.post_type    = 'TWO_POST_TYPES'
    AND post_date       >= '$startdate'
    AND post_date       <= '$enddate'
    GROUP BY wposts.ID
    ";
```

I am trying to put two different custom post types into the `wposts.post_type` part, which we can call `type1` and `type2`. What I have already tried is the following, with no luck:

1. `array('type1', 'type2')`
2. `'type1, type2'`

I have also tried passing both of these as variables in the query, but also no luck. Would anybody be able to give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
AND wposts.post_type IN ('type1', 'type2')
```

which actually means:

```
AND ( wposts.post_type = 'type1'
   OR wposts.post_type = 'type2'
    )
```